# can't understand why they neglected sum of n

Tags: calculus, summation, fourier-series

[image]

when they took integral of both sides then $\int \cos nwt \cos mwt dt$ will be equal to $0$ but $a_n$ stays but $\Sigma$ or sum of it  will be neglected so i don't understand why. We still have our $a_n$ with $n$. why do we have to get rid of it when we still have same coefficients on the formula?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that

$$
\cos(x \pm y) = \cos x \cos y \mp \sin x \sin y
$$

Therefore

\begin{eqnarray}
\cos (m + n)\omega t &=& \cos m\omega t \cos n \omega t - \sin m\omega t \sin n \omega t \\
\cos (m - n)\omega t &=& \cos m\omega t \cos n \omega t + \sin m\omega t \sin n \omega t
\end{eqnarray}

Adding both equations

$$
\cos m\omega t \cos n \omega t = \frac{1}{2}[\cos (m + n)\omega t + \cos (m - n)\omega t]
$$

Consider now two cases

> $m\not = n$

In this case both $m + n$ and $m - n$ are integers and

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^T {\rm d}t~ \cos m\omega t \cos n \omega t &=& \frac{1}{2} \int_0^T {\rm d}t~\cos (m + n)\omega t + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^T {\rm d}t~\cos (m - n)\omega t \\ &=& \left.\frac{1}{2\omega(m + n)}\sin (m + n)\omega t \right|_0^T + \left.\frac{1}{2\omega(m - n)}\sin (m - n) \omega t \right|_0^T \\
&=& \frac{\sin 2\pi (m + n)}{2\omega(m + n)} + \frac{\sin 2\pi (m - n)}{2\omega(m - n)} = 0
\end{eqnarray}

where I have used the fact that $\sin 2\pi k = 0$ for $k$ integer

> $m = n > 0$

In this case

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^T {\rm d}t~ \cos m\omega t \cos n \omega t &=& \frac{1}{2} \int_0^T {\rm d}t~\cos 2n \omega t \\
&=& \left.\frac{1}{4n\omega} \sin 2n \omega t\right|_0^T \\
&=& \frac{\sin 4\pi n}{4n\omega} = 0
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I understand this part but don't know where the sum gone? we still have there a small n but they neglected infinity sum anyway.... any ideas?

Comment: The reason is that every term of the sum is zero $a_n\times 0$, so the sum is zero

Comment: are u saying that infinity sum of n=1 will be equal to zero? if so a small n also should be equal to zero

Comment: and  by an×0 u mean Cross product of a small n and 0?

Comment: No, what I am saying is $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_n\cdot 0 = 0$

Comment: but a small n is not 0 in there...look at the below integral of frequency equal to a small n * T/2

Comment: ∫cosnwtcosmwtdt is equal to T/2 and they multiplied a small n to it Without infinite sum so i dont understand where the sum gone although we have a small n?

Comment: There are two terms, one for $a_0$ and other for $a_n$, $n \ge 1$, each has an integral in them. If $m\not= n$ both integrals go to zero